# SQL - Filtering using a very large population of unsorted filters

Tags: sql, filter

I have a large data set from which I would like to select a sample. The sample population has been chosen more or less at random so I can't use a range to pull these records. I need to use about 10k different values.

One way I can think of is to use a WHERE clause, but this feels inefficient and I'm not sure if it would also cause issues when executing...

WHERE UoD_ID = 3021235
OR    3021352
OR    3035235 ... x 10,000 filters

Cheers,

Comment: You have UoD_ID to use in where clause? How those will be choosen? Randomly or someone will select those?

Comment: Hint:  `IN`.  You seem to want `in`.

Comment: It depends on your DBMS: eg: SELECT column FROM table   ORDER BY RAND()   LIMIT 10000.. please give more details.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur Yes, I should have specified - the 10k samples have already been selected. I have their IDs and now need to pull more information about them from a wider population.

Comment: @GordonLinoff This looks like a winner, I can output a comma separated string, plug it into an in statement and hope my computer doesn't crash ;) - thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Put the values into another table and do a join?

Answer (score 0):

The either you can make a comma separated string with all those IDs and use it with `IN` clause like below:

```
WHERE UoD_ID in( 3021235,3021352, 3035235 ... x 10,000 )
```

Or you insert all those IDs in a table and use that table in where clause like below:

```
Insert into idtable values(3021235);
Insert into idtable values(3021352);
.
.
.

where UoD_ID  in (select UoD_ID  from idtable)
```

I would like to suggest you second option.